# How to GROUP BY the CONCAT_WS

Tags: sql, hive, concatenation

I am trying to run `concat_ws` function into `group by`, and I get the error below. Does mean that Hive doesn't support `concat_ws` into `group by`? If not, is there a different way to write it?

I have the following records in waterfall_table(which just have year，month and day):

```
Year, Month, Date, 
2018, 08, 09 
2019, 09, 27
2017, 09, 27
2019, 02, 27
2019, 01, 27
2019, 01, 30
2019, 09, 27
2017, 09, 27
2019, 02, 27
2019, 01, 27
2019, 01, 30
..., ..., ...
```

Is there a way I can use a query to group my records into some rows whereby all the year，month and day will be group together?

The end result of the query will be two rows:

```
realdate,num
2019-01-27, 4
2019-01-28, 23
2019-01-29, 34
2019-02-01, 8
2019-02-02, 4
```

I think the query should look something like this:

```
    select
        concat_ws('-', year, month, day) as realdate,count(*)
    from
        waterfall_table
    where
        concat_ws('-', year, month, day) between '2019-01-25' and '2019-02-10'
    group by  concat_ws('-', year, month, day)
    order by concat_ws('-', year, month, day) desc
    limit 100
```

Comment: update your question and add  a proper data sample and the expected  result .. and show  the exact error message  too

Comment: use one column to add full date to improve the query performance

Comment: Why `2019-01-27` have num: `4` ? there is only two date `2019-01-27` in your sample data

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
select
  cast( ltrim( year) +'-'+ltrim( month) +'-'+ltrim( day ) as date),count(*)
from
    (select 2018 year ,10 month,25 day union select 2017 year ,11 month,10 
    union select 2016 year ,8 month,14 )t1
where
  cast( ltrim( year) +'-'+ltrim( month) +'-'+ltrim( day ) as date) between cast('2017-01-25' as date) and  cast('2019-02-10' as date)
 group by  year,month,day
order by  cast( ltrim( year) +'-'+ltrim( month) +'-'+ltrim( day ) as date) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you need something like:

```
SELECT CAST( CONCAT(`YEAR`, '-', `MONTH`, '-', `DATE` ) AS DATE ) AS realdate, COUNT(*) as num
FROM your_table
GROUP BY realdate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the column alias in the GROUP BY  and ORDER BY clause

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', year, month, day) as realdate, COUNT(*)
FROM waterfall_table
WHERE CONCAT_WS('-', year, month, day) BETWEEN '2019-01-25' AND '2019-02-10'
GROUP BY realdate
ORDER BY realdate DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive is picky about aliases.  Try this:

order by realdate desc

Answer (score 0):

In ORDER BY use an alias:

```
with waterfall_table as
(
select stack(11,
'2018', '08', '09', 
'2019', '09', '27',
'2017', '09', '27',
'2019', '02', '27',
'2019', '01', '27',
'2019', '01', '30',
'2019', '09', '27',
'2017', '09', '27',
'2019', '02', '27',
'2019', '01', '27',
'2019', '01', '30') as (Year, Month, day)
)

select
        concat_ws('-', year, month, day) as realdate, count(*) as cnt
    from
        waterfall_table
    where
        concat_ws('-', year, month, day) between '2019-01-25' and '2019-02-10'
    group by  concat_ws('-', year, month, day)
    order by realdate desc
    limit 100;
```

Result:

```
OK
realdate        cnt
2019-01-30      2
2019-01-27      2
Time taken: 92.909 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

This Jira seems related: [HIVE-1449](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1449)